# Populating Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to retrieve records from database matching the given condition and they have to be displayed in `ListView`. The problem is only a single record is displayed in the `ListView`. But more than one record matching the condition are present in the database. Following is the code I have used:

```
dbh = new DataBaseHelper(DeliveryReportActivity.this);

SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();

millname = edt_mill_name.getText().toString();

ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
lv.setAdapter(null);

Cursor cursor = db.query(DataBaseHelper.deliverytable, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null);
if (!cursor.equals(""))
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {

            String sdbmname = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Millname"));

            String sdbyname = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Yarnname"));

            String sdbcno = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Counttno"));

            String sdbnocones = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("NOCones"));

            String sdbnwg = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Netweight"));

            String sdbgno = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Bagnum"));

            String sdbdate = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Date"));

            if (millname.equals(sdbmname)) {

                results.add("Mill Name : " + sdbmname
                        + "\nYarn Name : " + sdbyname
                        + "\nCount No  : " + sdbcno
                        + "\nNo of Cones: " + sdbnocones + "\n"
                        + "Date : " + sdbdate
                        + "\nNet Weight: " + sdbnwg
                        + "\nNo of bags: " + sdbgno
                        +"\n ------------------------------------");

            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DeliveryReportActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
```

Comment: Debug your code

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of things

1. Don't use:
   if (!cursor.equals(""))
   This seems to be incorrect way to check if cursor is valid
2. Don't use do/while block. Just start with while(cursor.moveToNext())
3. Your condition filters just text if it matches milname text field
4. Ensure your condition is valid wile running loop times. Probably either run in debugger or use Log.d() to print if it doesn't mates. Then you can evaluate the condition of it's truly met.

Answer (score 0):

If the DB query is right, then the code is correct. I would suggest the following changes though.

- Get the trimmed string from your `EditText`.
- Check for `null` value in the `cursor` inside the if statement.

So here's the changes will look like.

```
millname = edt_mill_name.getText().toString().trim();

Cursor cursor = db.query(DataBaseHelper.deliverytable, null, null,
        null, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            String sdbmname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Millname"));
            String sdbyname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Yarnname"));
            String sdbcno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Counttno"));
            String sdbnocones = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOCones"));
            String sdbnwg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Netweight"));
            String sdbgno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Bagnum"));
            String sdbdate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date"));

            if (millname.equals(sdbmname)) {
                results.add("Mill Name : " + sdbmname
                        + "\nYarn Name : " + sdbyname
                        + "\nCount No  : " + sdbcno
                        + "\nNo of Cones: " + sdbnocones + "\n"
                        + "Date : " + sdbdate
                        + "\nNet Weight: " + sdbnwg
                        + "\nNo of bags: " + sdbgno
                        +"\n ------------------------------------");
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

However, it would be great if you could execute the database query so that only the rows matched with the provided `millname` will only be fetched. So the database query should look like the following.

```
millname = edt_mill_name.getText().toString().trim();
dbh = new DataBaseHelper(DeliveryReportActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.deliverytable + " where Millname = '" + millname + "'", null);
```

This would return only the rows matched with the given value. So that you don't have to add a filter again to insert those in your `result`.

Hope that helps!